Uniswap minting liquidity
I am trying to create uniswap V3 pool. token0 is always 490_000_000 * 1e18 tokens , token1 is changeable , between 1 -100 WETH ( WETH is also 18 decimals)
function createPool(
        address memeTokenAddr
    ) external payable onlyAllowedContracts returns (address) {
        // Approve the meme token
        IERC20(memeTokenAddr).approve(address(positionManager), TOKEN_FOR_DEX);
        IERC20(address(weth)).approve(address(positionManager), msg.value);

        // Deposit collected ETH as WETH
        weth.deposit{value: msg.value}();

        // Check or create pool
        address pool = uniswapFactory.getPool(
            memeTokenAddr,
            address(weth),
            500
        );
        if (pool == address(0)) {
            pool = uniswapFactory.createPool(memeTokenAddr, address(weth), 500);
        }

        

        // TOKEN_FOR_DEX is always 490_000_000 (18 decimals)
        // msg.value is changeable , around 1 -100 WETH (18 decimals )

        uint256 price = TOKEN_FOR_DEX / msg.value; 

        uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = uint160((sqrt(price) * 2 ** 96));

        // Initialize the pool with the calculated sqrtPriceX96
        IUniswapV3Pool(pool).initialize(sqrtPriceX96);

        INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams
            memory params = INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
                token0: memeTokenAddr,
                token1: address(weth),
                fee: 500,
                tickLower: -887220,
                tickUpper: 887220,
                amount0Desired: TOKEN_FOR_DEX,
                amount1Desired: msg.value,
                amount0Min: 0,
                amount1Min: 0,
                recipient: DEAD_ADDRESS, // burn the liquidity
                deadline: block.timestamp + 10 minutes
            });


        // Create pool
        (, , uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) = positionManager.mint(params);


        return pool;
    }

I've tried this code in Base Sepolia network with 2.931 WETH (2.931 * 1e18) but pool took so less token,
Base sepolia fork output
amount of WETH doesn’t  matter i have tried different amount of WETH, pool takes so less memeToken every time.
So i tried  to change  places of tokens , i tired to calculate price like this
// I've changed places of tokens but here TOKEN_FOR_DEX is so big and price becomes zero
// and transactions reverts.

uint256 price = msg.value / TOKEN_FOR_DEX;  

        uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = uint160((sqrt(price) * 2 ** 96));

        // Initialize the pool with the calculated sqrtPriceX96
        IUniswapV3Pool(pool).initialize(sqrtPriceX96);

        INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams
            memory params = INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
                token0: address(weth),
                token1: memeTokenAddr,
                fee: 500,
                tickLower: -887220,
                tickUpper: 887220,
                amount0Desired: msg.value,
                amount1Desired: TOKEN_FOR_DEX,
                amount0Min: 0,
                amount1Min: 0,
                recipient: DEAD_ADDRESS, // burn the liquidity
                deadline: block.timestamp + 10 minutes
            });

So i tried to make trick
        uint256 price = msg.value * 1e18 / TOKEN_FOR_DEX;  //prevent price to be zero 

        uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = uint160((sqrt(price / 1e18) * 2 ** 96)); //take back 1e18 effect

        // Initialize the pool with the calculated sqrtPriceX96
        IUniswapV3Pool(pool).initialize(sqrtPriceX96);

        INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams
            memory params = INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
                token0: address(weth),
                token1: memeTokenAddr,
                fee: 500,
                tickLower: -887220,
                tickUpper: 887220,
                amount0Desired: msg.value,
                amount1Desired: TOKEN_FOR_DEX,
                amount0Min: 0,
                amount1Min: 0,
                recipient: DEAD_ADDRESS, // burn the liquidity
                deadline: block.timestamp + 10 minutes
            });

but reverted again ...
why is pool taking so less memeToken? what am i miscalculating?
